# join-fetch associated entity by default

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

My Hibernate/JPA model has this entity classes

```java
@Entity
public class Student {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    // other properties, getters, setters, etc. omitted
}
```

This student-course relationship is unidirectional i.e. there is no reference to the `Student` entity in `Course`.

The default fetch type for `@ManyToOne` is eager, so the annotation above is the same as `@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`.

So whenever I execute a query that fetches students, the associated courses are also fetched, e.g.

```sql
select s
from Student s
where s.name = 'Bob'
```

However, although the courses are fetched at the same time, a separate query is issued to fetch them. If I want to fetch the student(s) and course(s) in a single query, I need to explicitly include a `join fetch` in my JPQL query, e.g.

```sql
select s
from Student s
join fetch s.course
where s.name = 'Bob'
```

As it's tedious and error prone to apply this update to all my student queries, is it possible to make join-fetching the default behaviour? In other words, to have the first query (without an explicit join) behave like the second query (join-fetch course by default)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility, I'm afraid. The `join` clause have semantics that may affect the query, so it would be dangerous to add a default clause. Consider an example like yours, but where the `course` relation is optional. A `join fetch s.course` would limit the result to students that have a course reference (it is an inner join after all), and students without courses (or with invalid course references) would simply be invisible to the query.

The [JPA 3.1 specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1#a4931) states that

> A FETCH JOIN enables the fetching of an association or element collection as a side effect of the execution of a query.

Unless you prove that there are considerable performance advantages of fetching it all in one query, I would recommend settling with the default behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

}
============================================
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Course {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Student> students;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "First?" Is this not a complete solution?

Comment: What do you mean by term "First?"

Comment: Did you not read [what you wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78037149/1)?

Comment: I read that, I wanted to say, first define student and then course entity. Apologies for mistake

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Lajos and General Grievance for your suggestion. I really appreciate that